# Permission denied when executing perl via sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, perl, environment-variables

Command:

`ssh user@testhost "sudo -u tester env PERL5LIB=/home/tester/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/tester/perl5/bin/testperl"`

Result: 

`Can't locate testperl.pm:   Permission denied at /home/mogile/perl5/bin/testperl line 15.`

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `perl @INC` contains `dot` (current directory), but the current directory (ssher's home directory) cannot be accessed by the executor `tester`, so the perl interpreter complains about it.

The solution: ask sudo use bash login session, i.e., `sudo -i -u tester env PERL5LIB=/home/tester/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/tester/perl5/bin/testperl`, then the current directory will be tester's home directory and sure he has the permission to access it.